# LiteralControlBuilder any example?

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I have been using `LiteralControl` to add direct HTML code to webpages for long time, but I just found out about `LiteralControlBuilder`. I first thought it would be a mix of `StringBuilder` and `LiteralControl`, but apparently is not. The code below compiles but crashes when executing.

```
 LiteralControlBuilder builder = new LiteralControlBuilder();
 builder.AppendLiteralString("<div>");
 builder.AppendLiteralString("<p>" + speech.Text + "</p>");
 builder.AppendLiteralString("<p>" + speech.From + "(" + speech.When + ")</p>");
 builder.AppendLiteralString("</div>");
 Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(builder.ToString()));
```

The exception is at the line `builder.AppendLiteralString("<div>");` and the message is:

> Property '' does not have a property named 'text'.

Any idea how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > The ASP.NET parser uses this
   >       class to generate HTML for any
   >       Literal controls on a requested Web
   >       Forms page. You will not need to use
   >       this class directly in application
   >       code.

   http://learning.infocollections.com/ebook%202/Computer/Programming/ASP.Net/ASP.NET.in.a.Nutshell.Second.Edition/0596005202_ch42-77213.html
2. There is a method *Init* you have to call first.